# theano index out of bound and shape mistaken in theano.scan

Tags: theano

I'm writing my codes in dl4mt (an open source neural machine translation tool)
I encountered some weird problems in theano scan.
The following code was used to extract sub-tensor from a 3D tensor according to some indices.

the "indicesSub" in line 1098 is of shape (n_sample, window)
"sl" in 1099 is (n_sample, )
"cc_" in line 1100 is of shape (n_timestep, n_sample, dimctx),
the results of cc_result should be of shape (nsample, window, dimctx)

so in line 1116, where cc_ was already dimshuffled to shape (n_sample, n_timestep, dimctx), the three inputs are all sequences.

In the inner loop (_sub_step), indices is used as sequence parameter, the other two are non_sequences. The error occurs when training, which I will put on in the end. But when I use some trick to train a pseudo model and using it to test, the error doesn't show... Which is really weird because training and testing share the same codes.

The error is really weird, too. It says the input shape is (17, 256), (256, ), (), respectively. But according to my codes, the input shape should be (17, 256), (21, ), (), where 21 is window size.

I'm wondering if there's something that could change the input of scan? maybe a None input? I'm not sure. Please help me if you have any idea. Thank you

```
1098         indicesSub = indices_mask_[src_positions]       # n_samples, window                                                                                                    
1099         sl = sntlens.reshape([sntlens.shape[0], ])      # (n_sample, )                                                                                                         
1100         ccshuffle = cc_.dimshuffle(1, 0, 2)      # n_sample, n_timestep, dimctx                                                                                                
1101                                                                                                                                                                                
1102         def _step_index(indices, cc_sub, sntlen_in):                                                                                                                           
1103             def _sub_step(indice_step, cc_step, len_step):                                                                                                                     
1104                 # indice_step is a scalar                                                                                                                                      
1105                 # cc_step is (ntimestep * dimctx)                                                                                                                              
1106                 # sntlen_in is a scalar                                                                                                                                        
1107                 r = tensor.switch(tensor.lt(indice_step, 0), 0, 1)                                                                                                             
1108                 l = tensor.switch(tensor.ge(indice_step, len_step), 0, 1)                                                                                                      
1109                 rt = ifelse(tensor.lt(r * l, 1), tensor.zeros([cc_step.shape[1], ]), cc_step[tensor.cast(indice_step, 'int64')])                                               
1110                 return rt                                                                                                                                                      
1111             ret, updt = theano.scan(_sub_step,                                                                                                                                 
1112                                      sequences=indices,                                                                                                                        
1113                                      non_sequences=[cc_sub, sntlen_in])                                                                                                        
1114             return ret                                                                                                                                                         
1115                                                                                                                                                                                
1116         cc_result, upd = theano.scan(_step_index,                                                                                                                              
1117                                 sequences=[indicesSub, ccshuffle, sl])                                                                                                         
1118
```

Error info:

```
 24   File "theano/scan_module/scan_perform.pyx", line 397, in theano.scan_module.scan_perform.perform (/search/odin/chengshanbo/.theano/compiledir_Linux-2.6-el6.x86_64-x86_64-with-redhat-6.6-Santiago-x86_64-2.7.    11-64/scan_perform/mod.cpp:4193)                                                                                                                                                                                
 25   File "/search/speech/chengshanbo/tools/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg/theano/scan_module/scan_op.py", line 951, in rval                         
 26     r = p(n, [x[0] for x in i], o)                                                                                                                                              
 27   File "/search/speech/chengshanbo/tools/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg/theano/scan_module/scan_op.py", line 940, in <lambda>                     
 28     self, node)                                                                                                                                                                 
 29   File "theano/scan_module/scan_perform.pyx", line 405, in theano.scan_module.scan_perform.perform (/search/odin/chengshanbo/.theano/compiledir_Linux-2.6-el6.x86_64-x86_64-with-redhat-6.6-Santiago-x86_64-2.7.    11-64/scan_perform/mod.cpp:4316)
 30   File "/search/speech/chengshanbo/tools/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/link.py", line 314, in raise_with_op                           
 31     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)                                                                                                                                     
 32   File "theano/scan_module/scan_perform.pyx", line 397, in theano.scan_module.scan_perform.perform (/search/odin/chengshanbo/.theano/compiledir_Linux-2.6-el6.x86_64-x86_64-with-redhat-6.6-Santiago-x86_64-2.7.    11-64/scan_perform/mod.cpp:4193)
 33   File "/search/speech/chengshanbo/tools/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg/theano/scan_module/scan_op.py", line 951, in rval                         
 34     r = p(n, [x[0] for x in i], o)                                                                                                                                              
 35   File "/search/speech/chengshanbo/tools/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg/theano/scan_module/scan_op.py", line 940, in <lambda>                     
 36     self, node)                                                                                                                                                                 
 37   File "theano/scan_module/scan_perform.pyx", line 405, in theano.scan_module.scan_perform.perform (/search/odin/chengshanbo/.theano/compiledir_Linux-2.6-el6.x86_64-x86_64-with-redhat-6.6-Santiago-x86_64-2.7.    11-64/scan_perform/mod.cpp:4316)
 38   File "/search/speech/chengshanbo/tools/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.8.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/link.py", line 314, in raise_with_op                           
 39     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)                                                                                                                                     
 40   File "theano/scan_module/scan_perform.pyx", line 397, in theano.scan_module.scan_perform.perform (/search/odin/chengshanbo/.theano/compiledir_Linux-2.6-el6.x86_64-x86_64-with-redhat-6.6-Santiago-x86_64-2.7.    11-64/scan_perform/mod.cpp:4193)
 41 IndexError: index out of bounds                                                                                                                                                 
 42 Apply node that caused the error: GpuIncSubtensor{Inc;int64}(GpuElemwise{add,no_inplace}.0, if{inplace,gpu}.0, ScalarFromTensor.0)                                              
 43 Toposort index: 5                                                                                                                                                               
 44 Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix), CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector), Scalar(int64)]                                                                               
 45 Inputs shapes: [(17, 256), (256,), ()]                                                                                                                                          
 46 Inputs strides: [(256, 1), (1,), ()]                                                                                                                                            
 47 Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown', 17]                                                                                                                                   
 48 Outputs clients: [['output']]                                                                                                                                                   
 49
```